# How to manually add a cookie in opera 12.17?

Tags: opera, cookies

I have to test some functionality on a web page using Opera 12.17. Therefore I need to create a cookie with a specific value beforehand.

How can I create a new cookie for a specific host in Opera?

I'm only able to edit existing cookie values through the preferences dialog.

Comment: You could use javascript... there are many resources. First link in Google was http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: unfortunately this won't work with httpOnly - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999360/how-do-i-set-the-httponly-flag-of-a-cookie-with-javascript

Comment: Can I also guess you can't use http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/ (also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613522/opera-browser-cookie-editor )

Comment: @DaveRook I'm able to use the bundled version of dragonfly that comes with 12.17, but I haven't found out how to use it to edit cookies.

Comment: @DaveRook Seems that I have overlooked that possibility. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You can use [Opera Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/), which is bundled with Opera any way.

You can invoke it by the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or by menu **Page> Developer Tools> Opera dragonfly**, then use the "Storage" tab (The "Cookies" sub tab should be the default), double click on an entry to edit it.

Source: [Opera browser - cookie editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613522/opera-browser-cookie-editor)

For later versions of Opera, [EditThisCookie](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/edit-this-cookie/?display=en) is a cookie manager. You can add, delete, edit, search, protect and block cookies.  [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) is also available for Chrome

From the plug in:

- EditThisCookie is a cookie manager. You can add, delete, edit, search,
  protect and block cookies!
- Inspired by the lack of a good cookie manager in google chrome i
  developed this small simple and extremely useful extension, that let's
  you perform anything you might actually need to do with cookies
- ★ Delete any cookie ★ Edit any cookie ★ Add a new cookie ★ Search a
  cookie ★ Protect a cookie (read-only) ★ Block cookies (cookie filter)
  ★ Export cookies in JSON, Netscape cookie file (perfect for wget and
  curl), Perl::LPW ★ Import cookies in JSON ★ Limit the maximum
  expiration date of any cookie

Comment: unfortunately EditThisCookie requires a newer version of Opera than 12.17.